# Configure log4j to log all but one level

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Using log4j or log4j2 is it possible to configure a logging appender (or a logger) to match all levels but one? E.g. if I want to log all but INFO to one appender (that is, log levels both above and below INFO, but not INFO)?

Answer (score 0):

Updated from comments. You can use  [LevelRangeFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/LevelRangeFilter.html) as per D.B. suggestion or create custom level logger.

Levels are ordered (log4j2) as

```
Standard Level  intLevel
OFF                0
FATAL             100
ERROR             200
WARN              300
INFO              400
DEBUG             500
TRACE             600
ALL           Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Therefore if you set `log.setLevel(Level.WARN);` it will log only WARN, ERROR and FATAL levels.

You can create custom level  with `0<intLevel<100` to log only there.
See [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html)

Comment: Good point. A custom logging level at the 'edges' will achieve exactly what I need. Don't know why I didn't consider creating one with level 0-99. Thanks!

Comment: But that point aside I don't get why this isn't achieveable using appenders and filters... ;)

Comment: It is possible - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56301185/3284624)

Comment: Exactly what I want! -Great! :)